# Setting loop inside a Recursive function

Tags: r, function, loops, recursion

I have the following recursive function that works on calculating the BOM accumulative prices from from A(raw material), B(sub-assembly) and to C(finished product), from the data frame "df".

```
adjust_price <- function(df, maxLevel = max(df$productionlevel), level = maxLevel - 1) {
  condition <- df$productionlevel == level & df$itemtype != "A"
  if (any(condition)) {
    higherLevel <- level + 1
    df[condition, 'final_price'] <- sum(df[df$productionlevel == higherLevel, 'final_price']) * df[condition, 'quantity']
  }
  if (level >= 0 ) {
    adjust_price(df, maxLevel = maxLevel, level = level - 1)
  } else {
    return(df)
  }
}

df$final_price = 0
df[df$price != 0, 'final_price'] <- df[df$price != 0, 'quantity'] * df[df$price != 0, 'price']

adjust_price(df)
```

```
structure(list(item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", 
"i7", "i8", "i9"), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 
5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "C"), productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 0), final_price = c(4, 10, 15, 7, 10, 0, 16, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

. Now if I have different products C(finished products) how can I use this function to be applied when I group by the finished products based on the new data frame?

Here is the updated data frame:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(product_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2"), item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", 
"i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", 
"i17", "i18"), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 
5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"
), productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

I want to adjust my recursive function to be able to calculate the final prices for each product_id separately using the same function. Would be a loop inside the recursive function applicable or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you desired output is, but we can `group_by(product_id)` and use the `adjust_price()` function in a `group_modify()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

# preprocessing
df2$final_price = 0
df2[df2$price != 0, 'final_price'] <- df2[df2$price != 0, 'quantity'] * df2[df2$price != 0, 'price']

df2 %>% 
  group_by(product_id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ adjust_price(.x))

#> # A tibble: 18 x 7
#> # Groups:   product_id [2]
#>    product_id item_id quantity price itemtype productionlevel final_price
#>    <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 P1         i1             2     2 A                      3           4
#>  2 P1         i2             2     5 A                      3          10
#>  3 P1         i3             5     3 A                      3          15
#>  4 P1         i4             1     7 A                      3           7
#>  5 P1         i5             1    10 A                      2          10
#>  6 P1         i6             2     0 B                      2          72
#>  7 P1         i7             4     4 A                      1          16
#>  8 P1         i8             1     0 B                      1          82
#>  9 P1         i9             1     0 C                      0          98
#> 10 P2         i10            2     2 A                      3           4
#> 11 P2         i11            2     5 A                      3          10
#> 12 P2         i12            5     3 A                      3          15
#> 13 P2         i13            1     7 A                      3           7
#> 14 P2         i14            1    20 A                      2          20
#> 15 P2         i15            2     0 B                      2          72
#> 16 P2         i16            4     2 A                      1           8
#> 17 P2         i17            1     0 B                      1          92
#> 18 P2         i18            1     0 C                      0         100
```

Data from OP

```r
adjust_price <- function(df, maxLevel = max(df$productionlevel), level = maxLevel - 1) {
  condition <- df$productionlevel == level & df$itemtype != "A"
  if (any(condition)) {
    higherLevel <- level + 1
    df[condition, 'final_price'] <- sum(df[df$productionlevel == higherLevel, 'final_price']) * df[condition, 'quantity']
  }
  if (level >= 0 ) {
    adjust_price(df, maxLevel = maxLevel, level = level - 1)
  } else {
    return(df)
  }
}

df2 <-
structure(list(product_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
                              "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
                              "P2"), item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", 
                                                 "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", 
                                                 "i17", "i18"), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
                                                                             5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 
                                                                                                             5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                                                                                                                    "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"
                                                                                                             ), productionlevel = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                                                    2, 2, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
                                                                                                                                    ))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In base R, using a split-apply-combine approach:

```
df2$final_price <- df2$quantity * df2$price

df2 <- lapply(split(df2, df2$product_id), adjust_price)
do.call(rbind, c(df2, make.row.names = FALSE))
```

```
   product_id item_id quantity price itemtype productionlevel final_price
1          P1      i1        2     2        A               3           4
2          P1      i2        2     5        A               3          10
3          P1      i3        5     3        A               3          15
4          P1      i4        1     7        A               3           7
5          P1      i5        1    10        A               2          10
6          P1      i6        2     0        B               2          72
7          P1      i7        4     4        A               1          16
8          P1      i8        1     0        B               1          82
9          P1      i9        1     0        C               0          98
10         P2     i10        2     2        A               3           4
11         P2     i11        2     5        A               3          10
12         P2     i12        5     3        A               3          15
13         P2     i13        1     7        A               3           7
14         P2     i14        1    20        A               2          20
15         P2     i15        2     0        B               2          72
16         P2     i16        4     2        A               1           8
17         P2     i17        1     0        B               1          92
18         P2     i18        1     0        C               0         100
```